# isnt everything where it should be, why the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

this is the little code-snippet that causing segmentation fault, and I don't get why...

```
char *firstName[50];
char *lastName[50];

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter ++) {           
        fscanf(config, "%s %s\n", firstName[counter], lastName[counter]);
```

shouldnt this code scanf config file take the first and second string, and store them separately in firstName[0,1,2.. counter] and lastName[counter] ?

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for your strings. As written, you have memory for 50 pointers in each array.

Comment: A pointer must point to *something*. Now, all of your pointers – all 100 of them – point somewhere but you don't know where to. It could be empty space, your back yard, or the ceiling – but you don't know, and the data goes somewhere unknown.

Comment: you were right, didnt thought about memory allocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
char *firstName[50];
```

`firstName` is **array of 50 character pointer**, and if you want to store anything into each of these **char pointer**, you need to allocate memory for them. For e.g

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter ++) {
        firstName[counter] = malloc(SIZE_FIRST); /* memory allocated for firstName[counter], now you can store into it */ 
        lastName[counter] = malloc(SIZE_LAST);           
        fscanf(config, "%s %s\n", firstName[counter], lastName[counter]);
}
```

Once done with processing of `firstName` and `lastName` free the dynamically allocated memory to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: yeah, absolutely correct, didn't thought of memory allocation

Comment: For illustrative purposes, it would be better to test allocation success and avoid potential undefined behavior.